# Compare two columns of two files and display the third column with input if it matching of not in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to compare the first two columns of two files file1.txt and file2.txt and if they match to write to another file output.txt with the third column of both file1,file 2 along with details if it matches or not .

file1.txt

```
ab|2001|name1
cd|2000|name2
ef|2002|name3
gh|2003|name4
```

file2.txt

```
xy|2001|name5
cd|2000|name6
ef|2002|name7
gh|2003|name8
```

output.txt

```
name1 name5  does not match
name2 name6  matches
name3 name7  matches
name4 name8  matches
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at `awk`?

Comment: yes , but I wasn't able to print out the third column of the first file

Comment: Then please be specific and show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;b[$2]=$3;next} ($2 in a) && ($1==a[$2]){print b[$2],$3,"matched properly.";next} {print b[$2],$3,"Does NOT matched."}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk -F"|" '
FNR==NR{
   a[$2]=$1;
   b[$2]=$3;
   next
}
($2 in a) && ($1==a[$2]){
   print b[$2],$3,"matched properly.";
   next
}
{
   print b[$2],$3,"Does NOT matched."
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -F"|" '                                 ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as | here.
FNR==NR{                                    ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1.txt is being read.
   a[$2]=$1;                                ##Creating an array with named a whose index is $2 and value is $1.
   b[$2]=$3;                                ##Creating an array named b whose index is $2 and value is $3.
   next                                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                           ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
($2 in a) && ($1==a[$2]){                   ##Checking condition if $2 is in array a AND first field is equal to value of array a value of index $2.
   print b[$2],$3,"matched properly.";      ##Printing array b value with index $2 and 3rd field with string value matched properly.
   next                                     ##next will skip all statements from here.
}                                           ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
{
   print b[$2],$3,"Does NOT matched."       ##Printing value of array b with index $2 and 3rd field with string Does NOT matched here.
}
' file1.txt file2.txt                       ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: can you please explain the logic in this answer?

Comment: @Donbhupi, Sure lemme add in few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use paste and awk to get what you want.

Below solution is assuming the fields in file1 and file2 will be always delimited by "|"

```
paste -d "|" file1.txt file2.txt | awk -F "|" '{ if( $1 == $4 && $2 == $5 ){print $3, $6, "matches"} else {print $3, $6, "does not match"} }' > output.txt
```