# Join files based on two columns using awk

Tags: unix, awk, text-processing

I have the following two files;

```
$ cat file1
1 4
2 5
3 6

$ cat file2
4 2 N1
4 1 Y1
6 2 N2
6 3 Y2
2 5 Y3
```

I am interested in the third column of `file2`. So I want to join the two files based on two first columns which are ID columns. After much searching ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994298/properly-join-two-files-based-on-2-columns-in-common), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703905/compare-two-columns-of-two-files-and-display-the-third-column-with-input-if-it-m) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004437/how-to-compare-multiple-columns-in-two-files-and-retrieve-the-corresponding-valu/36005018#36005018) for example) I tried a few things and it works in principle;

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];next}; ($1, $2) in a || ($2, $1) in a{print $3}' file1 file2
Y1
Y2
Y3
```

Or,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}; ($1, $2) in a || ($2, $1) in a{print $0, a[$1,$2]}' file2 file1
1 4
2 5 Y3
3 6
```

However not my exact desired output;

```
1 4 Y1
2 5 Y3
3 6 Y2
```

The order of IDs in `file1` is important as first column is for example males and second females. In `file2` the columns maybe either males or females.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1 OFS $2]; next}
     ($2 OFS $1) in s {
         print $2, $1, $3
     }
     ($1 OFS $2) in s {
         print $1, $2, $3
     }' file file2
```

Comment: better! not exaclty because i require the same column as in file1. See desired output..

Comment: your answered inspired my own solution, `awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1 OFS $2]=$3; next}($2 OFS $1) in s || ($1 OFS $2) in s{if(s[$1 OFS $2]=="") print $0,s[$2 OFS $1]; else print $0,s[$1 OFS $2]}' file2 file1`

Comment: Ok, changed my answer as well.

Comment: Awesome :), better than my version

Comment: Nice. Glad to see that it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not very short, but does the job:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$1 FS $2;a[$2,$1]=a[$1,$2];next}; ($1,$2) in a || ($2,$1) in a{print a[$1,$2],$3}' file1 file2

1 4 Y1
3 6 Y2
2 5 Y3
```

Alternative:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$1 FS $2;next}; {pr=0};($1,$2) in a {pr=a[$1,$2]};($2,$1) in a{pr=a[$2,$1]};pr{print pr,$3}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Just as you answered i stumbled upon a solution inspired by @hek2mgl; `awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1 OFS $2]=$3; next}($2 OFS $1) in s || ($1 OFS $2) in s{if(s[$1 OFS $2]=="") print $0,s[$2 OFS $1]; else print $0,s[$1 OFS $2]}' file2 file1`.