# How to use awk tool to associate two files for query？

Tags: awk

During my interview, the interviewer asked me a question about awk, and I couldn’t do anything about it.

Question is as follows：
Filename `a.txt` contains the `userId` and `zoneId`, and filename `b.txt` contains the `zoneId` and `zoneName`.
Requirements: Use the awk tool to print out the zoneName to which the userId of a.txt belongs.

For example:

`a.txt` like this:

```
u001 z001
u002 z002
u003 z003
```

`b.txt` like this:

```
z001 A
z002 B
z003 C
```

The print result is as follows:

```
u001 A
u002 B
u003 C
```

Thank you very much for your answers！

---

The meaning of this question is to let us use two files as an internal link.

Like this in SQL:`a.txt inner left join b.txt`

I look up information and think the following is an ideal answer：

`awk -F' ' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;}NR!=FNR && a[$1] {print a[$1], $2}' a.txt b.txt`

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This might help: [Join files based on two columns using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48619486/3776858)

Comment: You can make it a little bit shorter as: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' b.txt a.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `a.txt` content be

```
u001 z001
u002 z002
u003 z003
```

and `b.txt` content be

```
z001 A
z002 B
z003 C
```

then

```
awk 'FILENAME=="a.txt"{user[$1]=$2}FILENAME=="b.txt"{zone[$1]=$2}END{for(i in user){print i,zone[user[i]]}}' a.txt b.txt
```

output

```
u001 A
u002 B
u003 C
```

Explanation: I create array `user` from data from file `a.txt` and array `zone` from data from file `b.txt`, so providing `userId` as key for `user` will result in corresponding `zoneId` and providing `zoneId` as key for `zone` will result in corresponding `zoneName`. After data is collected I `print` for every key in `user` that key and retrieve `zoneId` from `user` which then I use to retrieve `zoneName`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*